# How to specify credentials when connecting to Dynamics CRM web service?

Tags: web-services, authentication, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Can someone explain to me how to specify authentication for the Dynamics CRM web service? My current attempts have yielded nothing:

```
  var svc =  new CrmServiceSoapClient("CrmServiceSoap");
  svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = Resources.UserName;
  svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Resources.Password;
  svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Resources.UserName;
  svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Resources.Password;
  return svc;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a X509 certificate (native .NET class) and passing it to the service?

Comment: It looks like you are using a WCF-Client. Are you using Dynamics CRM 4? It is not possible to access Dynamics CRM 4 with a WCF-Client. 

See http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/78a1a90c-a8e6-4611-9c3a-f9d03a743063

Answer (score 1):

I do one of these (might not be the exact code, but you get the idea):

```
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
svc.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new ClientCredential("", "", "");
```

Comment: That doesn't help - I'm still getting "The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."